# Processing result from multiple observables to database and adding to database once

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I need to process 2 different API data results I get by observable with getData() and getAnotherData() and save the result to the database.
I don't like the way I have to check when both observable's data are processed. Is there anything you would do differently?

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

class dataClass {
  data: any;
  id: string;

  constructor (id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.proccess()
  }

  proccess() {
    let i = 0;
    this.getData(this.id).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.data = {
          // process API data
        }
      }, 
      undefined, 
      () => this.onLoad(++i)
    );
    this.getAnotherData(this.id).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.data.another = {
          // process API data
        }
      }, 
      undefined, 
      () => this.onLoad(++i)
    );
  }

  getData(id):Observable<any> {
    // return JSON API obserable
  }

  getAnotherData(id):Observable<any> {
    // return JSON API obserable
  }

  onLoad(i) {
    if (i == 2) {
      // send processed data back to db
      firebase.database()
        .ref('/test/' + this.channel.id)
        .update(this.data, this.onError);
    }
    return;
  }

  onError(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error: ' + error);
    } else {
      console.log("Data saved successfully.");
    }
  }
}
var adm = new dataClass("id");
```

Comment: Is the data from both observables processed the same way?

Comment: @0mpurdy no, that's why I had to split them.

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the question (it's late here) You could use [merge](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) and do `onLoad` when the merged observable completes (you'd just be ignoring the merged stream I think) [Rx marbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#merge) try dragging the marbles (including the complete) to see what would happen. Is that what you're asking? I'd better check before posting an answer in case I've got it wrong again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to simplify the implementation.

`forkJoin` takes a number of observables and emits an array containing their last-emitted values when all of the observables have completed.

Also, you can use `mergeMap` to compose the promise returned by the `update` call into the observable stream.

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

Observable.forkJoin(
  this.getData(this.id),
  this.getAnotherData(this.id)
)
.mergeMap(([data, anotherData]) => {
  this.data = data;
  this.data.another = anotherData;
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/test/' + this.channel.id)
    .update(this.data);
})
.subscribe(undefined, this.onError);
```

Comment: Muchos kudos! :)